# Additional computed fields in Model

Tags: python, django, django-models

I have two simple models in my Django app. Here's what they look like:

```
class Host(models.Model):
    url = models.URLField(max_length= 200)
    ssl = models.BooleanField(default = False)

class Query(models.Model):
    host = models.ForeignKey(Host)
    date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add = True)
    latency = models.FloatField(null = True)
    success = models.BooleanField(default = False)
    error = models.CharField(max_length= 2000, null = True)
```

When i access the `Host` model, I only have access to the two fields `url` and `ssl`. When querying the `Host` model, I would like three extra fields to computed and returned dyanmicaly. These are the `average_latency` which would be the average of the not-null latency field of all the child `Query` records so i can access it something like this:

```
t = Tracker.objects.get(id = 1)
t.url
t.average_latency
```

Could someone please explain how I can do this or point me to some examples/documentation?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just use [class properties](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#property):

```
class Host(models.Model):
    .
    .
    .
    @property
    def average_latency(self):
        # calculate latency from Query model ...
        return latency
```

Bear in mind that this is a read-only property.

Comment: Note that if a derived field computation is expensive it might be worth caching it and updating when the related fields change... Its not an easy problem.

Answer (score 1):

You can check [django-denorm](http://django-denorm.initcrash.net/tutorial.html), it's pretty much about what you're trying to achievie. I also have some flashbacks that there are other similar django apps.